# How does CLLocationManager get location?

Tags: ios, gps, location

TL;DR: 
My objective: Try all forms of getting a location and then choose the most accurate one, (try get a location for a minute then time out).

I'm a little confused about where it gets the location from, is it GPS? Cellular? or a mix of both depending on toolkit?

While getting location on Android I used both and then choose which provider based on accuracy. I do not see anything similar for iOS.

I'm using CLLocationManager which is showing good accuracy but I'm not sure where the location is from.

Comment: All I care about is a co-ordinate, no other information associated. If its only GPS then how can I get a location from cellular?

Comment: @iphonic, I highly recommend you to read documentation and rely on facts, before advising something. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, location manager is built more intelligently. Relying on your configuration, it either uses GPS or WiFi/cell radios, as described in the `CLLocationManager` documentation:

> For the services you use, configure any properties associated with
>   that service accurately. Core Location manages power aggressively by
>   turning off hardware when it is not needed. For example, setting the
>   desired accuracy for location events to one kilometer gives the
>   location manager the flexibility to turn off GPS hardware and rely
>   solely on the WiFi or cell radios, which can lead to significant power
>   savings.

For more information, read
[CLLocationManager documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager).

**EDIT**

And, If you want the most accurate location, you should put `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` for location manager's `desiredAccuracy` property.

Comment: I never seen CLLocationManager working if GPS hardware turned off. I am saying this by my experience not by documentation. Can you prove this that CLLocationManager works without GPS? It will be good to know.

Comment: Actually, when you turn off the location on iOS device, you don't turn off only the GPS, you turn off location services, which includes all location mechanisms those could identify your location. If it was GPS only, then they would write GPS in the Settings, right? And, it would be very stupid of Apple if they rely only on GPS to determine location.

Comment: You can't turn off GPS, I meant Location Services. In my comment I have written if you turn off Location Services, `CLLocationManager` doesn't give you any location. Behind the scene CLLocationManager is using GPS and Network. I have given another solution for that as well, if CLLocationManager fails, you can still get location by using your network IP.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, this clears things up a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! If this solved your problem, don't forget to accept it.